# How do I pass a MultipartFile from Java to Python?

Tags: java

I was calling a Python program from Java, thus:

```
String[] command = {"python.exe", "script.py", fileIn};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = probuilder.start();
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

where fileIn was a String.

Works great, but now I need to pass a MultipartFile (ie a file, not just its name) but I do not know how to pass it to Python.

Comment: "ie a file, not just its name" - do you mean an absolute path instead of just the name? Or do you want to pass a byte stream instead of a path?

Comment: Thanks. A byte stream, or whatever MultipartFile is.

Comment: either use sockets or one of various platform-dependent interprocess communication techniques

Comment: another solution is to temporary save the bytes in a file and pass the absolute path to python to read it

Comment: @Pali could you explain just a little more?

Comment: Either use the output stream on the process builder to push the data to python's stdin via a pipe or write the multipart to a temporary file on disk and pass the name to python.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Could you give an example as an answer?

Comment: Is your MultipartFile the Spring class?

Comment: `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your multipart file is the Spring class then they have some convenient methods for saving the file to disk.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...

MultipartFile file =...;
Path tempFolder = ...;
Path tempFile = Paths.get(tempFolder.toString(), file.getName());

file.transferTo(tempFile);

//now the tempFile should have the data.
String[] commands = {"python.exe", "script.py", tempFile.toAbsolutePath().toString()};
```

That should create a file with the filename, and save it in the folder then start python with the file path as an argument.

To be clear, the `...` are indicating code I do not know. I don't know how you created a MultipartFile, and I don't know where you want your temp folder. For testing purposes you can use `Path tempFolder = Paths.get(".");` or something relevant. Also I have assumed the multipart file is the spring class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)

Comment: Struggling a bit. Could you add the imports please?

Comment: @schoon I added the only two imports that I used, Path and Paths. The other one is the Spring class.